# Algolia Instant Search - how to not do the initial search?

Tags: algolia

I've been following the example for Algolia's Instant Search at https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/instant-search/ (javascript version)

I understand that for many use-cases (like in the example) it makes sense for the script to run its initial search upon pageload and display the results (basically all results).
In my case though I'd like to not do that initial search. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass a `searchFunction` parameter to the `instantsearch` initializer, which will intercept each search and let you decide whether to perform it or not.

Here's an example taken from this [Github issue](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/4). The search is not performed if the query is empty, as it will be on page load.

```
var search = instantsearch({
  searchFunction: function(helper) {
    if (helper.state.query === '') {
      return;
    }

    helper.search();
  }
});
```

If you have your own logic around when the search should/shouldn't be performed you can use it in here. See the [Usage tab](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#initialization) of the Initialization section of the docs for more information.

Comment: Good but when searching for a term, then removing it, search hits remain open. This comment does the trick: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/4#issuecomment-199321325

Comment: To close the searches when search term is removed with backspace, I completed the answer here: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/4#issuecomment-343935278

Comment: Also to remove pagination add->       document.querySelector('#pagination').innerHTML = '';

Comment: helper.state.query was unedined intially, so I returned if `helper.state.query === undefined`